# Rails: asset 404 when served by apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an API that generate png files.

The user request the generation, and I reply with a path to the generated files.

This is how I generate the URL:

```
url_for(:controller => :anaction, :action => :download, :path => "#{@relative_dir}/face", :format => 'png'
```

This yeild an URL that looks like:

> ```
> http://0.0.0.0:3000/anaction/aging/download/%2FTMP_20161128204315_346482_695%2Fface.png
> ```

That should be handled by

```
  def download
    send_file "#{Rails.public_path}/#{params[:path]}.#{params[:format]}"
  end
```

According to my route

```
  get '/anaction/aging/download/:path' => 'mpsynthesizer_aging#download'
```

It works like a charm on my dev environment, on my nginx server, but fail on my apache server.

I get a plain apache HTTP400 error, it seems that the request is never forwarded to rails.

I use rails 4.2.6

Is there something i misunderstood ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
    render body: IO.binread(result_file), content_type: "image/png"
```